# Citing Wikipedia with APA Formatting and BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa6

Wikipedia's entry on [citing Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCiting_Wikipedia) says that APA formatting requires that their page on plagiarism be formatted as:

> Plagiarism. (n.d.). In Wikipedia. Retrieved August 10, 2004, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism

In particular, the APA format requires the article name to take the place of the author.

To cite Wikipedia with BibTeX, they say to use the code:

```
@misc{ wiki:###,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title = "Plagiarism --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
   year = "2004",
   url = "\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Plagiarism&oldid=5139350}",
   note = "[Online; accessed 22-July-2004]"
 }
```

This however, puts Wikipedia as the author, among other things (and is therefore not in APA format).

The package I am using is `apacite` and the code I have for my bibliography is:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{FinalRoughDraft}
```

I have tried things like setting putting the title of the article in the `author = ...` field, but if I put, say, `author = Estimation lemma`, the output in the author position is "lemma, E." I have also tried putting quotation marks around the title, but this does not work either.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You can do `author = "{Estimation lemma}"`. The extra braces are proving an extra group without sorting. I am sure we have such a question somewhere.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's have a TeX and a BIB file:

### Code

#### `wiki.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url,apacite}    % package url to prevent horrible linebreaks
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
\cite{wiki:xxx}
\bibliography{wiki}
\end{document}
```

#### `wiki.bib`

```
@misc{ wiki:xxx,
  author = {{Estimation lemma}},
  title = "Estimation lemma --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
  year = "2010",
  url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Estimation_lemma&oldid=375747928",
  note = "[Online; accessed 29-September-2012]"
}
```

### Output

[image: compiled example]

### Notes

Notice the use of double braces: `{{Estimation lemma}}`.
The inner pair hides these *two* words from BibTeX so that it only "sees" one string.

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler than the solution I finally came up with. After I posted this question, I toyed with the code a bit I tried inserting \hspace{4pt} between "Estimation" and "lemma". It worked, but I think this is much simpler lol

Comment: What should be the entry at year? I notice that the year is different from the date and year of online access? Does the later indicate the date on which I am opening that page on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do for [APA 7th](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/wikipedia-references) Wikipedia formatting:

Add the following (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525955/eliminating-words-in-citation-format-either-doi-or-retrieved-from#526083)) to suppress the "Retrieved from" text that comes from apacite:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{}}  % remove "Retrieved from" for reference links
```

then format your Wikipedia article like this:

```
@misc{website:ZookeeperWiki,
    author       = {{Apache ZooKeeper}},
    month        = {December},
    day          = {1},
    url          = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Apache_ZooKeeper&oldid=992755046},
    year         = {2019},
    howpublished = {In \textit{Wikipedia}},
}
```

Citation should look like:

Apache ZooKeeper. (2019, December 1). In *Wikipedia*. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Apache_ZooKeeper&oldid=992755046