# How to cite SEVERAL articles of Wikipedia (if all labels are wiki:xxx)?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

[Citing one article is as follows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74578/citing-wikipedia-with-apa-formatting-and-bibtex):

```
@misc{ wiki:xxx,
  author = {{Estimation lemma}},
  title = "Estimation lemma --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
  year = "2010",
  url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Estimation_lemma&oldid=375747928",
  note = "[Online; accessed 29-September-2012]"
}
```

But, how to cite a SECOND article? `@misc{ wiki:yyy,` ?

Or maybe `@misc{ wiki:xxx,` actually means `@misc{ wiki:001,` ?

Comment: If your key is `wiki:xxx` then use `\cite{wiki:xxx}`. If your key is `wiki:001` use `\cite{wiki:001}`. The keys are completely arbitrary and are equal to whatever you set them to in the `.bib` file.

Comment: OK. Thank you! I'll use something like `wiki:estimationlemma` then. Feel free to write an answer...

Comment: Are all the labels identical? Try making each one unique

Answer (score 1):

If your key is `wiki:xxx` then use `\cite{wiki:xxx}`. If your key is `wiki:001` use `\cite{wiki:001}`. The keys are completely arbitrary and are equal to whatever you set them to in the `.bib` file.

If duplicate keys are present in the `.bib` file, BibTeX uses the first occurrence.